# Get substring between "first two" occurrences of a character

Tags: java, string, java-8, substring

I have a `String`:

```
 String thestra = "/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/eee";
```

Every time, in my situation, for this Sting, a minimum of two slashes will be present without fail.

And I am getting the `/aaa/` like below, which is the subString between "FIRST TWO occurrences" of the char `/` in the String.

```
 System.out.println("/" + thestra.split("\\/")[1] + "/");
```

It solves my purpose but I am wondering if there is any other elegant and cleaner alternative to this?

Please notice that I need both slashes (leading and trailing) around `aaa`. i.e. `/aaa/`

Comment: is this string, by any chance, a filepath?

Comment: Its a String only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Scanner::findInLine`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#findInLine(java.lang.String)) returning the first match of the pattern may be used:

```
String thestra = "/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/eee";
System.out.println(new Scanner(thestra).findInLine("/[^/]*/"));
```

Output:

```
/aaa/
```

Comment: Wow. too much to learn. !!! This looks super cool. I never used `findInLine` before. Definitely will give it a try. What about the performance negotiation/trade-off using this compared to the solution which I am using?

Comment: @AjayKumar of course, `split` does a lot of unnecessary work for your task. Then, you’re performing string concatenation. So this `Scanner` approach is likely more efficient, though, just `thestra.replaceFirst("[^/]*(/[^/]*/).*", "$1")` might be even more efficient. In either case, if you’re performing this operation more than once, it might be more efficient to use `Pattern.compile` once and re-use this object. `findInLine` support specifying a prepared `Pattern` instead of `String`, for the replace-first approach you would invoke `.matcher(thestra).replaceFirst("$1")` directly on the pattern

Answer (score 6):

You can use `indexOf`, which accepts a second argument for an index to start searching from:

```java
int start = thestra.indexOf("/");
int end = thestra.indexOf("/", start + 1) + 1;
System.out.println(thestra.substring(start, end));
```

Whether or not it's more elegant is a matter of opinion, but at least it doesn't find every `/` in the string or create an unnecessary array.

Answer (score 2):

Use Pattern and Matcher from `java.util.regex`.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("/.*?/");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
if (matcher.find()) { 
    String match = matcher.group(0);  // output
}
```

Comment: I liked it. What is significance of `*` here?

Comment: `*` => zero or more times.
`?` => greedy, i.e. stop at the first search
`.` => any character

Comment: Ahem, `.*?` is *reluctant*, the opposite of greedy. The `.*` would be greedy, so it would match up to the last `/` but `.*?` is reluctant so it matching up to the next `/`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Pattern.compile("/.*?/")
            .matcher(thestra)
            .results()
            .map(MatchResult::group)
            .findFirst().ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

You can test this variant :)

With best regards, Fr0z3Nn

Comment: `Stream.limit(1).forEach(System.out::println)` could be used instead of `findFirst` returning `Optional`

Answer (score 1):

One of the many ways can be replacing the string with group#1 of the [regex](https://regex101.com/r/Cxfch2/1), `[^/]*(/[^/].*?/).*` as shown below:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String thestra = "/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/eee";
        String result = thestra.replaceAll("[^/]*(/[^/].*?/).*", "$1");
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
/aaa/
```

**Explanation of the regex:**

- `[^/]*` : Not the character, `/`, any number of times
- `(` : Start of group#1

  - `/` : The character, `/`
  - `[^/]`: Not the character, `/`
  - `.*?`: Any character any number of times (lazy match)
  - `/` : The character, `/`
- `)` : End of group#1
- `.*` : Any character any number of times

---

**Updated the answer as per the following valuable suggestion from [Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2711488/holger)**:

Note that to the Java regex engine, the `/` has no special meaning, so there is no need for escaping here. Further, since you’re only expecting a single match (the `.*` at the end ensures this), `replaceFirst` would be more idiomatic. And since there was no statement about the first `/` being always at the beginning of the string, prepending the pattern with either , `.*?` or `[^/]*`, would be a good idea.

Comment: Note that to the Java regex engine, the `/` has no special meaning, so there is no need for escaping here. Further, since you’re only expecting a single match (the `.*` at the end ensures this), `replaceFirst` would be more idiomatic. And since there was no statement about the first `/` being always at the beginning of the string, prepending the pattern with either , `.*?` or `[^/]*`, would be a good idea.

Comment: Thanks, @Holger for the valuable suggestion. I've copied it to the answer because sometimes comments get deleted. I escaped `/` just because I wanted to put a demo with regex101.com as well and using the same pattern in my code. However, I forgot to mention the same in the answer. Your comment completes that now .

Comment: Well, it works with regex101.com too. You just have to select the “Java 8” flavor on the left-hand side, https://regex101.com/r/zg5N5K/1/

Answer (score 1):

> Every time, in my situation, for this Sting, minimum two slashes will be present

if that is guaranteed, split at each `/` keeping those delimeters and take the first three substrings.

```
String str = String.format("%s%s%s",(thestra.split("((?<=\\/)|(?=\\/))")));
```

Comment: Its giving me `Open the Java > Compiler > Errors/Warnings preference page and highlight the 
 problem to configure its severity.

Problem: Type String[] of the last argument to method format(String, Object...) 
 doesn't exactly match the vararg parameter type. Cast to Object[] to confirm 
 the non-varargs invocation, or pass individual arguments of type Object for a 
 varargs invocation.` What is that?

Comment: @AjayKumar An issue of varargs and arrays. Both `String.format(string, (Object)…)` or `String.format(string, (Object[])…)` could be meant and the compiler wants to be sure that you know what your’e doing. Replace `String.format("%s%s%s",…` with `String.join("",…` and not only the warning will disappear, it will be way more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

You could also match the leading forward slash, then use a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `[^/]*` to optionally match any character except `/` and then match the trailing forward slash.

```
String thestra = "/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/eee";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("/[^/]*/");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(thestra);

if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

Output

```
/aaa/
```

Answer (score 1):

I am surprised nobody mentioned using [Path](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html) as of Java 7.

```
String thestra = "/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/eee";
String path = Paths.get(thestra).getName(0).toString();
```

```
System.out.println("/" + path + "/");
```

```
/aaa/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String thestra = "/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/eee";
System.out.println(thestra.substring(0, thestra.indexOf("/", 2) + 1));
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 